# Prevent a view from being loaded or appearing

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tab bar controller as the starting point of my app, where one of the tab and what happens subsequently is meant for admins only. So I was password protecting a tab. I thought of adding a little modal dialogue in the `viewDidLoad` function of my view controller (which by the way is a `UITableViewController`),

Suppose I can get the text that the user entered in the dialogue box in the variable `inputTextField`.

The relevant section of the code from `viewDidLoad()`:

```
if inputTextField?.text != "secret" {
    return
} 
super.viewDidLoad()
```

But it does not work. Any hint appreciated. Sorry if it is too basic, I am completely new to iOS and Swift programming, so pardon my ignorance folks.

Comment: Define "it does not work". It doesn't show up? It doesn't accept the password? It accepts any password? The password check should be in `viewWillLoad()`, not `viewDidLoad()`, so that the controller can be aborted if the password is wrong.

Comment: By "it does not work", I meant the view shows up anyway even if the password entered did not match. I tried to use viewWillLoad() but UITableViewController does not have a method viewWillLoad().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example.  Lots of ways.  I dropped two UIViews in Storyboard on the first tab's VC.  The one in the back I gave a dark color to simulate the hidden secret view (secretView).  Inside of the view on top (entryView) I dragged a label "Enter Passcode" and a text field (passCode).  I just hid the back view unless the secret code was correct.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.passCode.delegate = self
        entryView.hidden = false
        secretView.hidden = true
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var entryView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secretView: UIView!
    let secretCode = "X"

    @IBOutlet weak var passCode: UITextField!


    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

        if textField.text == secretCode {

            entryView.hidden = true
            secretView.hidden = false

        } else {

            self.passCode.text = "Try Again!"
        }

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above by dragging 2 UIViews into a exiting VC, and it worked. Thanks much. Is it possible to do this for 2 different VCs. That is without putting 2 views into the same VC. I also played around by making tabbarcontoller child class and hoping to catch tab presses in shouldSelectViewController. But no luck so far.

Comment: Absolutely!  One way would be to segue to another view controller upon a correct answer.  Let me know if you ned help with the code.